# How to do SELECT ... WHERE ... IN in ClojureQL?

Tags: clojure, clojureql

*I just worked this one out. Since it's not in the documentation and needs you to dig into the source, this seemed the right venue for the solution.*

In ClojureQL, how do you create a query like:

```
SELECT * from foo where id in (1, 5, 7);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `in` predicate from the predicates namespace, e.g.

```
(require '[clojureql.core :as ql])
(require '[clojureql.predicates :as pred])
(ql/select (ql/table :foo) (ql/where (pred/in :id [1 5 7])))
```

Comment: Having to reference the predicate namespace is a bug in ClojureQL 1.0.1, see https://github.com/LauJensen/clojureql/issues/100